# Segmentation Fault with Desktop Save Mode (emacs 26.3.50)

Tags: debugging, desktop, crash

When I try to run emacs 26.3.50 (built from source), it gives me the following warning: "Warning: desktop file appears to be in use by PID .... Using it may cause conflicts. Use it anyway? (y or n)". If I select "y", after several seconds it quits and the following error is produced:

```
Fatal error 11: Segmentation fault
Backtrace:
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x5072fe]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x4ece6a]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x50581e]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x505a38]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x505abc]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890)[0x7f0e498eb890]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXft.so.2(XftCharIndex+0xd)[0x7f0e4a9bb68d]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x5c8b29]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x45ad79]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x433180]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x43df5d]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x446f4a]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x4507ce]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x42f428]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x4551da]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x4554ef]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x45565c]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x559b5d]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x562ee2]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x599c70]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x562e5d]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x599c70]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x562e5d]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x599c70]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x562e5d]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x599c70]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x565953]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x564eca]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x566dab]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x56204e]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x4ed290]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x561fbd]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x4ed1a8]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x4f1d73]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x4f2096]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x416129]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x7f0e48d4ab97]
./src/emacs-26.3.50.1[0x416d7a]
```

My .emacs is as follows:

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "/home/ricercar/src/replace-colorthemes")

(package-initialize)

(define-key special-event-map [config-changed-event] #'ignore)
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 90)
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(custom-enabled-themes '(blippblopp))
 '(custom-safe-themes
   '("780c67d3b58b524aa485a146ad9e837051918b722fd32fd1b7e50ec36d413e70" "6a674ffa24341f2f129793923d0b5f26d59a8891edd7d9330a258b58e767778a" "5c83b15581cb7274085ba9e486933062652091b389f4080e94e4e9661eaab1aa" default))
 '(fill-column 80)
 '(package-selected-packages
   '(sql-indent emacsql emacsql-mysql emacsql-psql emacsql-sqlite magit project-explorer helm company-box jinja2-mode web-mode auto-complete neotree projectile auctex tabbar-ruler mode-icons powerline tabbar))
 '(send-mail-function 'mailclient-send-it)
 '(tab-width 4)
 '(tabbar-mode t nil (tabbar)))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
;; C STYLE AND TAB SETTINGS
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(setq-default c-default-style "stroustrup")
(defvaralias 'c-basic-offset 'tab-width)
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)

;; SCROLL SETTINGS
(setq scroll-step 1)
(setq mouse-wheel-progressive-speed nil)
(setq mouse-wheel-scroll-amount '(1 ((shift) . 1))) ;; one line at a time

;; NEOTREE SETTINGS
(require 'neotree)
(global-set-key [f8] 'neotree-toggle)

;; TABBAR SETTINGS
(global-set-key [C-iso-lefttab] 'tabbar-backward-tab)
(global-set-key [C-tab] 'tabbar-forward-tab)

;; AUTO FILL SETTINGS
(setq-default fill-column 80)
(setq-default auto-fill-function 'do-auto-fill)

;; AUTO COMPLETE SETTINGS
(global-auto-complete-mode 1)       

;; PROJECTILE SETTINGS
(projectile-mode 1)
(define-key projectile-mode-map (kbd "s-p") 'projectile-command-map)
(define-key projectile-mode-map (kbd "C-c p") 'projectile-command-map)
(setq projectile-project-search-path '("~/src"))
(global-auto-complete-mode 1)
(column-number-mode 1)

;; UNDO TREE
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/ricercar/src/undo-tree")
(require 'undo-tree)
(global-undo-tree-mode)

;; COLUMN ENFORCE
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/ricercar/src/column-enforce-mode")
(require 'column-enforce-mode)
(global-column-enforce-mode 1)

;; PROJECT EXPLORER
(global-set-key [f9] 'project-explorer-open)

;; HIDE SHOW
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook (lambda() (hs-minor-mode)))

;; MISCELLANEOUS
(blink-cursor-mode 0)
(global-linum-mode 1)
(column-number-mode 1)
(global-visual-line-mode 1)
(desktop-save-mode 1)
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 90)

;; DISABLED COMMANDS
(put 'scroll-left 'disabled nil)
(put 'upcase-region 'disabled nil)
(put 'downcase-region 'disabled nil)

;; MAGIT SETTINGS
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x g") 'magit-status)
```

If I remove the line `(desktop-save-mode 1)`, or select "n" for the aforementioned prompt, emacs 26 runs just fine (except I can't save the session of course). Also, emacs 27 for some reason runs fine even with desktop-save-mode on. But I would prefer not to have to resort to using the latest development version on a daily basis.

Any idea how I might go about fixing this?

Comment: Please consider reporting the problem: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. Pretty much any crash indicates a basic Emacs bug somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

When saving the desktop file, emacs used to also save which font-backend is being used by the various frames it has open. Emacs-26 on GNU/Linux by default uses the `xft` backend, whilst emacs-27 can use the `ftcr` (Cairo) backend, so that's what it saves in the desktop file. That wouldn't normally be a problem, except that until recently, emacs would crash if you tried to switch font backends for a frame, so when you go back to emacs-26 with a desktop file saved by emacs-27, it crashes.

The desktop package no longer saves or restores the font-backed in emacs-27, and the crashing bug has been fixed as well. See https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=23386 and https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=38442

Easy fix if you don't want to upgrade: remove the `(font-backend ftcr)` and `(font-backend ftcrhb)` forms from your desktop file.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.  If you delete the `.emacs.desktop` file the problem goes away. The file will be re-created when you exit Emacs.  I've tried a few times to start and exit Emacs without further crashes.  Could it be a problem with the `.emacs.desktop` file format (i.e. after an upgrade of the `desktop` package)?

Comment: The crash is a problem in Emacs's C code (almost by definition of a "segmentation fault") rather than in the `desktop` package (although that problem might indeed be triggered by something in the `desktop` package).